# How can I check how many USB ports are available on my computer in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, usb

I am using an Xavier NX, and one of the USB ports doesn't seem to be working for the board I am using with the Xavier NX. I want to check if the ports is available as I am not seeing any devices that I connect to the USB port. Is there a way to check if the system sees the port before connecting the device? e.g., can I list available USB ports (rather than listing connected devices)?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and the USB port is accessed on the board via a 20-pin ZIF connector.

Comment: You're going to have trouble with this, since there's separate concepts of controllers, hubs, and ports. Some ports may be directly on a controller. Some (most?) ports, including those on a motherboard, will be going through a hub. Some hubs will have all their ports physically present. Other hubs will present ports that are not physically connected to a real port. From software, you can't really tell without manually connecting devices and mapping out the virtual <=> physical ports.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `hwinfo`

`sudo apt-get install hwinfo`

If you do not want to install an app, try running `cat /proc/mounts`

Another thing you can try, which lists active USB devices, is `lsusb`.

`lsdev | less` will list all hardware devices. When looking for USB devices, look for either objects labeled as USB or objects labeled as PCI. I really hope this is a helpful answer.

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/426199/how-to-list-your-computers-devices-from-the-linux-terminal/

Comment: This outputs over 10k lines in the terminal. Do you have an idea what to look for in the output?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I am going to fix my answer and provide better information...

Comment: I just updated it and added a couple of commands to try.

Comment: Click on the URL if you need more help.

Comment: If you want us to review some output, edit your question and *post the output*.  If it's so excessively long that you think it would be a distraction in the body of your question, upload and link to https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

> can I list available USB ports (rather than listing connected devices)?

Try this: `lspci | grep -i usb`